# Returning String Content to a specific index only

Tags: java

Here I have the following classes below. How do I get my wordValidation() method to provide the wordContent to provide output only to the word found and its index. 
For sample output using my test program below if I have a consonant word like "BCGAYYY", how do I provide output only to the wrong character in this case  A(because A is not a consonat), to get an output like "BCGA" + index?

I have the method wordValidation() below however this provides the whole word and its index...

```
public abstract class Words {
    private String wordDetail;
    private String wordContent;

    public Words(String wordDetail, String wordContent) throws InvalidWordException{
    this.wordContent = wordContent;
    this.wordDetail = wordDetail;
    wordValidation();



    }

    public String getWordDetail() {
        return this.wordDetail;
    }

    public String getWordContent() {
        return this.wordContent;

    }

    public abstract String AcceptedCharacters();

    public void wordValidation() throws InvalidWordException{

          String content = getWordContent();
        String theseletters = this.AcceptedCharacters();


        for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
            char c = content.charAt(i);
            if (theseletters.indexOf(c) == -1) {
                throw new InvalidWordException(content, i);

            }
        }

    }

    public String toString(){
    return  getWordDetail() + getWordContent();

    }
```

Checked Exception

```
public class InvalidWordException  extends Exception {

    public InvalidWordException (String wordContent, int theIndex) {
        super("Wrong Word" + wordContent + theIndex);
    }


}
```

Concrete Class 1

```
public class Vowels extends Words {
    private String validVowels;

    public Vowels(String wordDetail, String wordContent) throws InvalidWordException {
        super(wordDetail, wordContent);
    }

    @Override
    public String AcceptedCharacters() {
        return validVowels = "AEIOU";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Vowels vowel = new Vowels("First Vowel Check" ,"AEIOXAEI");
        } catch (InvalidWordException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

concrete class 2

```
public class Consonants extends Words {
  private String validConsonants;
    public Consonants(String wordDetail, String wordContent) throws InvalidWordException{
        super(wordDetail, wordContent);
    }

    @Override
    public String AcceptedCharacters() {
        return validConsonants ="BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVXZWY";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
          Consonants consonants = new Consonants("First Consonant Check","BCGAYYY");
      } catch (InvalidWordException ex) {
          System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      }

    }
}
```

test program

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
          Consonants consonants = new Consonants("First Consonant Check","BCGAYYY");
      } catch (InvalidWordException ex) {
          System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `throw new InvalidWordException(content, i);`

to

`throw new InvalidWordException(content.substring(0,i), i);`

In Java, String objects are immutable. So you were passing the original content string as is. That's why it is not giving you your desired output.

Comment: Thanks you are great.